# How to proof the partial sum of convex sets is convex set with the convex preserving operation?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**Proof:**
If $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are convex sets in $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, then their   partial sum:
$$S=\{(x,y_{1}+y_{2})|x\in \mathbb R^{m},y_{1},y_{2}\in\mathbb  R^{n},(x,y_{1})\in S_{1},(x,y_{2})\in S_{2})\}$$
is still convex.

It seems that the convex preserving operation is needed.But I can't get the $x$ in $(x,y_{1}+y_{2})$ through $(x,y_{1})$ and $(x,y_{2})$
with the convex preserving operation.

I hope you can help me.Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\
(x,y_{1}+y_{2}) = \begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y_1+y_2 \\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           0.5x + 0.5x \\
           y_1+y_2 \\
         \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           0.5x\\
           y_1 \\
         \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
           0.5x\\
           y_2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$
Note $\begin{bmatrix}
           0.5x\\
           y_1 \\
         \end{bmatrix} \in U_1$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
           0.5x\\
           y_2 \\
         \end{bmatrix} \in U_2$. Here $U_1, U_2$ are convex sets. Why? Hint: Affine Transform of convex set. Do you now see convex preserving operation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the accepted answer is correct. Just because the first coordinate is denoted $x$ the same way in both $U_1$ and $U_2$ does mean they are the same $x$.

Here is my attempt. Let $(x_1, y_1) \in U_1$ and $(x_2, y_2) \in U_2$. Then their Cartesian product is convex: $C = U_1 \times U_2 = (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$. Now, consider the set $S = (x, \mathbf{R}, x, \mathbf{R})$. This is a line and is clearly convex. The intersection of $S$ and $C$ is $(x, y_1, x, y_2)$ is convex. Now, the projection onto the 1st, 2nd and 4th coordinates $(x, y_1, y_2)$ is also convex. Then, apply the affine map $f(a, b, c) = (a, b+c)$, we are done.